# Django | Value error: "Invalid literal for int() with base 10:''

Tags: python, django

Devuelve error cada vez que la consulta no obtiene resultados. "listQuestionFromTestCounter" no obtiene resultados ¿Cómo lo podría evitar?
Un saludo.

**El error lo sa en la línea siguiente:**

```
if int(array10Numbers[0]) > 0:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código:**

```
#Seleccionar pregunta
listQuestionFromTestCounter = TestCounter.objects.get(user=username, modality=modalidadID)    
#Queryset de Testcounter (Modality/User)
number10QuestionList=listQuestionFromTestCounter.listQuestionsNumbers # Tomar string
array10Numbers = number10QuestionList.split(sep=',') #Pasar string a list
if int(array10Numbers[0]) > 0:
    numberNextQuestion=int(array10Numbers[counter])
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedo entrar en la parte de datos de tu error, porque no los has colgado, pero si puedo ayudarte a entender el error.

#### ValueError

Primero, identificar que la excepción es de tipo [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Esta diciendo que se esta asignando un valor no permitido.

#### Invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Segundo, cuando llamas al método `int()` estás convirtiendo el argumento a un dato de tipo `integer`. El argumento de esa excepción dice que el `literal` ( argumento introducido en el método, que puede ser un numero o un string) es inválido para un numero de base10. En base10 no hay decimales, ni letras, solo combinaciones de 0 a 9.

Seguramente que el resultado es un `string` cualquiera, o un `float`.

#### comprobación, depuración

Puedes poner un `print(array10Numbers[0])` antes del `if` para ver el resultado antes de que excepcione el script. O mejor si sabes depurar, ponle un `breakpoint` en la misma linea.

En caso de que sea un float, puedes convertirlo explicitamente `int(float()`, pero vas a perder resolución.